# How to combine on if statment if int number equal to element in the list of int?

Tags: python, random

Let's say I want to random number, but the number cannot be `i`, or number that is already in the list. How can I check against my list in the `if` statement?

I think I'm close to the answer:

```
if randlink == i or (randlink == x for x in listofnumbers):
    return randNumber(i, listofnumbers)
```

This function returns a number that did not appear before, this is the code:

```
def randNumber(i, listofnumbers):
    from random import randrange
    randlink = randrange(0, size)
    if randlink == i or [randlink == x for x in listofnumbers]:
        return randNumber(i, listofnumbers)
    return randlink
```

Comment: Use `random.sample` instead, something like `random.sample(range(size), n)`

Comment: Don't use recursion for such purposes. Just construct a `while` loop.

Comment: @FranciscoCouzo True, but we don't know if `listofnumbers` is automatically populated with the new random numbers.

Comment: nice!
but how i can avoid from generet number from 0 to size, exept number i?
for exmple:
i = 2
random.sample(range(0, 6), 3)

Comment: `random.sample(list(range(0, 3)) + list(range(4, size+1)))`

Comment: or `random.sample(set(range(0, size+1)) - 3)`

Answer (score 0):

The operator you are looking for is `in`:

```
if randlink == i or randlink in listofnumbers:
    ...
```

Recursion is a bad idea in this case, since your code may search for a long time. Use a loop instead:

```
randlink = randrange(0, size)
while randlink == i or randlink in listofnumbers:
    randlink = randrange(0, size)
return randlink
```

Don't use a list, since it has linear lookup. Use a set instead:

```
s = set(listofnumbers)
```

Do this once outside the function. The interface for lookup is the same:

```
while randlink == i or randlink in s:
```

Finally, sampling with rejection is generally not optimal. A better way is to figure out how map your sampling to the range you want.

In your code, you don't show an explicit correlation between `i`, `listofnumbers`, and `size`. You hint that this is some sort of attempt at sampling without replacement over a large range that you don't want to instantiate. The function [`random.sample`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/random.html#random.sample) was created for this exact purpose. If you pass in `range(size)` as the sequence, you will only need to allocate the samples that are actually picked, no matter how big `size` is.

Let's say that you want to generate `n` samples, and `i` is a random number you want to avoid. The contract of `random.sample` is that any subset has the same uniformity, so you can do the following:

```
numbers = set(random.sample(range(size), n + 1))
try:
    numbers.remove(i)
except KeyError:
    numbers.pop()
```

If you really want to preserve the original order as returned by `random.sample`, you can do it with a little more work:

```
numbers = random.sample(range(size), n + 1)
try:
    numbers.remove(i)
except ValueError:
    numbers.pop()
```

The `list` interface is almost identical to a `set` in this case, but much slower. The only difference is the exception type.

Answer (score 0):

You can check if it is in your list using

```
if randlink in listofnumbers:
```